# Apply the logic in an input string and convert the string

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

If user inputs the password as string and we want to apply below checks to convert the string.

1. If password is length is min 8 or max 12 then 1 else 0
2. First character of password is in Upper case then 1 else 0
3. Password has lower case letters then 1 else 0
4. Password includes special characters then 1 else 0
5. Password includes number and last character of the password is number then 1 else 0

For example input string:

```
"Ramesh@123"
```

Output string:

The output of the above input string is as below after applying the above all logics. Length of the string is 10 satisfies first condition so 1 then # first character is UPPER so 1 then #  string has lower letters 1 then # string has special characters so 1 then # and at last string has numbers and last character is number so 1.
So the final output will be :

```
"1#1#1#1#1"
```

could anyone please tell me how to achieve this in shell script

Comment: What are you trying to do with that output string? It makes it pretty hard to further process.

Comment: Have a look at [Get length of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash) and at   
[Check if string contains specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294902/bash-script-check-string-for-uppercase-letter)

Comment: How special is a "special" character?  Should it include control characters?